# Finding out whether a predicate logic formula is true or false.

Tags: predicate-logic

I'm given the formula: ∃x∃y∃z(P(x, y) ∧ P(z, y) ∧ P(x, z) ∧ ¬P(z, x)).

The universe is all natural numbers. R is the relation corresponding to P. R = {<x, x+1> : x >= 0}

When putting values into the formula I've thought that if x = x then y = x + 1. By using this logic z is equal to x for P(z, y), but z has to be equal to y for P(x, z). I can't think of any other way to do this.

How do I show whether the formula is true or false? Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't want you to solve it for me. I just want to be pointed in the right direction. Thank you so much!

Comment: That is the right direction.

Comment: I think you have shown that the formula is false under the given interpretation of $P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When putting values into the formula I've thought that if x = x then y = x + 1. By using this logic z is equal to x for P(z, y), but z has to be equal to y for P(x, z). I can't think of any other way to do this.

Indeed.   That is the way to do this.

Let's tidy up your work a bit.

---

You have $P:=\{\langle x, x+1\rangle: x\in\Bbb N^+\}$  Which means $P(x,y)$ is substitutable with $y=x+1$.   Okay, so we shall do that.

$$\exists x~\exists y~\exists z~(P(x, y) \land P(z, y) \land P(x, z) \land\lnot P(z, x))\\\equiv\\\exists x~\exists y~\exists z~(y=x+1 \land y=z+1 \land z=x+1 \land x\neq z+1)$$

Now, assuming this was true, we could find naturals $x,y,z$ where:

- $y=x+1$ and $z=x+1$, so $y=z$
- Also $y=z+1$, so $\underline{y=y+1}$

So...

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a ton. :)